# How can you prove this metric space exercise?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be a metric on $X$. Determine all constants $k$ such that:

(i) $kd$
(ii) $d+k$

is a metric on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly any positive rescaling of a metric is again metric and satisfies all the axioms. However regarding the second part $k+d(x,x)=0\Rightarrow k=0$